# Why is this external SVG gradient not showing up in a local SVG fill?

Tags: svg

I have the following SVG:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color: #e7d4ca; stop-opacity: 1" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color: #487c8c; stop-opacity: 1" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
    <rect x="0" y="0" rx="20" height="100%" width="100%" style="fill: url(#gradient)"></rect>
</svg>
```

Displayed as is, it works perfectly. But when I try to reference the gradient in this SVG as an external dependency in *another* SVG, it doesn't work:

```
<svg>
  <use xlink:href="external.svg#gradient"></use>
  <rect x="0" y="0" rx="20" height="100%" width="100%" style="fill: url(#gradient)"></rect>
</svg>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this...

```
<svg>
  <rect x="0" y="0" rx="20" height="100%" width="100%" style="fill: url(#external.svg#gradient)"></rect>
</svg>
```

assuming external.svg is on the same site as this file.